# Vertical navigation that stretches entire page

Tags: html, css, navigation, frontend

I need a vertical navigation that will stretch the entire screen. How can I do this?

Typically, I would set the navigation with:

```
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

but I can't get this to work for me for some reason or another. It shows a scroll bar regardless, and doesn't stretch the entire page--only the height of one viewport. You can view a working example here:

http://solstaging.net/vhosts/dealer-world-delivery/

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: relative` to your body tag and the #primary will be the full height.

Comment: works well enough. I don't know why the scroll appears when the page is empty, but the problem must be elsewhere. thanks!